# How to sum and group data for template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

For simplicity, assume a database with the following columns:

Table: Tickets

Columns:
Gender, Quantity, Date

where Gender can be M or F. A row is inserted for every purchase. Ultimately I want a stacked bar chart that shows the quantity purchased by males and females each month.

I can't seem to find a way to do this that doesn't require 2 queries, one that sums for M per month and one for F per month. The problem is that the query sets may not have the same number of objects and may not be in the same order by date.

I've tried:
set = Model.objects.filter(date__month = month).values('gender').aggregate(Sum('quantity'))

This sorts by date but doesn't separate M from F.
Adding M or F as a filter yields the correct quantity for one of the groups.

Using two queries(one for each of M, F) yields the correct quantities and date ranges but doesn't necessarily yield an identical number of sets. (eg. if in some months there are no purchases by M).

Thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: Should this not be  `Model.objects.filter(date__month = month).values('gender').annotate(total=Sum('quantity'))`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solved my error of grouping on the wrong data.

Comment: an upvote of would give me 2 reps and pls mark this as solved

Comment: Happy to but it seems your reply was as a comment rather than answer (?). I don't have an option for marking as resolved.

Comment: Nothing as easy as this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Statement :

```
Model.objects.filter(date__month = month).values('gender'). \
    annotate(total=Sum('quantity'))
```

in order to sum the quantity per gender per month